# Would there anyone tell me reason for this statement hold and give some hint?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$Q)$ Let the group $G$ and its normal subgroups $N$ and $M$. The orders of groups are  $\Vert G \Vert = 100$,  $\Vert M \Vert =25$ and $\Vert N\Vert =20$
Defining the homomorphsim $f$ and $g$ like the below

$f : G \to   G/M$ by  $f(x) = \bar x$ and $g : G \to   G/N$ by  $g(x) = \bar x$

Find the $c\in G$ $s.t. f(c) = \bar a$ and $g(c) = \bar b$ for given $\forall a, 
b(\neq a) \in G$

---

The answer sheet said 
considering the homo, $\phi : G \to G/M \times G/N $ by $\phi(x) = (f(x),g(x))$

The number of the $\beta$ is $\vert ker \phi \vert$ for $\phi^{-1}(\alpha) = \beta \bullet ker\phi$ (Here, $\phi(\beta)=\alpha$ ) **[statement(*)]**

The number of the $c$ is $\vert ker \phi \vert$ for $ \phi(c) = (\bar a, \bar b)$

Plus I did the another method motivated by $ker\phi = M \cap N$

My attempt)  I was motivated by the $ker \phi = M \cap N$.

So I tried to show the $c$ which are satisfying the $f(c) = \bar a $and $g(c) = \bar b$ would be $c \in M \cap N$

For $c \in G$, $f(a) = \bar a = aN = f(c) \Rightarrow \exists n \in N s.t. c = an$

Likewise $f(b) =  \bar b = bM = f(c)  \Rightarrow \exists m \in M s.t. c = bm$

So All I left to just showing $c  \in M\cap N$. But I've stuck.

Therefore my question is first, Why does the **statement (*)** hold? Second,What should I next to show $c  \in M\cap N$ in my trial?

Thanks.

Comment: I think your $g(x)=\overline{b}$ should be $g(c)=\overline{b}$.

Comment: $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$ if and only if $xy^{-1}\in\mathrm{ker}(\phi)$, if and only if $x=yz$ for some $z\in\mathrm{ker}(\phi)$. So the number of elements that map to $\alpha$ is either $0$ or $|\mathrm{ker}(\phi)|$. Otherwise, your question is a mess, and I am not at all clear what it is you are trying to prove in the first place.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Yes it was. and I edited the typo

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Actually I motivated by the solution that $ ker\phi = M \cap N$, so I tried to prove the $c \in \ker \phi$. So my intent in my trial was showing $c \in M\cap N$(Here the $c$ is $f(c) = \bar a$ and $g(c) =\bar b$  )

Comment: That’s nonsense; because if $c\in M\cap N$, then $f(c)=\overline{e}$ and $g(c)=\overline{e}$, and you are supposed to be showing that given **any** $a,b\in G$ you can find a $c$ (if I understand correctly). So if you pick $a\notin M$ and $b\notin N$, then $c\in M\cap N$ will *certainly* **not** work.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : Errr ..  I should have more considered about that. Thanks for taking out I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $f\colon G\to A$ and $h\colon G\to B$ are group homomorphisms, then the corresponding map $G\to A\times B$ given by $g\mapsto (f(g),h(g))$ has kernel $\mathrm{ker}(f)\cap\mathrm{ker}(g)$.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to show that given any $a,b\in G$, you can find $c$ such that $cM=aM$ and $cN=bN$.

Now, $G/M$ has order $4$, and $G/N$ has order $5$. So $(G/M)\times(G/N)$ has order $20$. Here, the kernel of your map into the product is $M\cap N$, which has order dividing $\gcd(|M|,|N|) = 5$. Thus, the kernel is either trivial or of order $20$. Since the image has order $|G|/|M\cap N|$, which must divide $20$, it follows that $M\cap N$ has order $5$, and hence that the map $G\to (G/M)\times (G/N)$ is surjective.

Given that the morphism is surjective, given $a,b\in G$, the element $(aM,bN)$ is in the image of the map, and hence there exists $c\in G$ that maps to $(aM,bN)$; that is, such that $cM=aM$ and $cN=bN$, which is what you want to establish.

Comment: Yes. You understood correctly What I've meant.